# step by step instructions on loading a csv into neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j Community edition 2.0.1 and have run into an issue which I cannot seem to resolve. I am trying to load a CSV file but am unable, keeps giving me the message of "type help to see valid commands". I used the same DB file that it says in the database location in the popup to connect, and created an import folder within that folder, and put the csv file there, but it will still not connect. The command I put is the following:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)
```

But, the error I get is:
Type :help for a list of available commands

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe LOAD CSV was only introduced in version 2.1 (you can see where it was added in the [2.1 changelogs](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-2.1-Community-changelog#210-m01)), so you won't be able to use this.

Neo4j 2.0.1 was released in 2014, you should seriously consider using/upgrading to a more recent version if possible.

Comment: I could only fine the Community edition download in this version. When I tried to download a different version, it did not give me an exe file so could not get it to work.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're looking at versions that are several years old? Check the [Neo4j Other Releases page](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/).

Comment: I tried that but could not figure out how to install it. There was no executable file with the zip download. Guess I am not sure which one to use.